# Referencing in Word does not show publication year in MLA

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a problem with MLA in Word; when I insert a reference, using the automatic function linking it to the Sources, the year does not show up, and since there are many works by a prolific writer, this means I have to keep the entire title in my reference to the work, which is pretty annoying. There are three little checkboxes in the dialog, and no matter how much I check and uncheck "year", it does not show up. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Software support is off-topic here.

Comment: @what It's a grey area; questions about writing-specific tools are on-topic. While that doesn't include general word processing software, I think the MLA features in Word are specific enough to qualify. However, this question would probably get more answers on superuser. Will cast the final close vote and send this over there.